# array of strings printing wrong values

Tags: c, arrays, string

I trying to make a program that calculates proper  prefixes and proper suffixes , and then compare the sets , and then return the array containing values representing number of matched
pairs , This could be used later in KMP algorithm . 
But the problem is prefixes and suffixes array give wrong values .
Even after appending a new element at new index, it replaces the all value in the array with the new element .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* lps(char *,int );

int main()
{

char *pat = "abababca";

int *ptr ;
ptr = lps(pat,strlen(pat));

printf("\n***LPS***\n");


}

int * lps (char *p,int s)
{


char *prefixes[s] ;
char *suffixes[s] ;
char tmp1[s] , tmp2[s];
int i , j , k , c1 , c2 , c;

for (i = 0 ; i < s ; i ++)
{
    printf("\n\n*** --- Creating Prefixes and Suffixes for i = %d --- ***",i);

    c1 = 0 ;
    //create prefixes
    for (j = 0 ; j < i; j++)
    {
        for (k =0 ; k <= j; k++)
        {
            tmp1[k]=*(p+k);
            printf("\n *(p+%d)= %c , tmp1[%d]=%c",k,*(p+k),k,tmp1[k]);
        }

        tmp1[k]='\0';
        printf("\nprefixes[0]:%s",prefixes[0]);
        prefixes[c1] = tmp1;
        //strcpy(prefixes[c1], tmp1);

        printf("\ncurrently added %s to prefixes at %d and prefixes[%d]= %s\n ",tmp1,c1,c1,prefixes[c1]);
        c1++;
    }

    //print prefixes
    for (k = 0; k<c1; k++)
    {
        printf("\tprefixes[%d] = %s",k,prefixes[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");



    //create suffixes
    c2 = 0;
    for (j = 1 ; j <= i; j++)
    {
        for (k = j ; k  <= i; k++)
        {
            tmp2[k-j] = *((p+k));
            printf("\n *(p+%d)= %c , tmp2[%d]=%c",k,*(p+k),k-j,tmp2[k-j]);
        }

         tmp2[k-j]='\0';
         suffixes[c2] = tmp2 ;
        // strcpy(suffixes[c2], tmp2);

         printf("\ncurrently added %s to suffixes at %d and suffixes[%d]= %s\n",tmp2,c2,c2,suffixes[c2]);
        c2++;
    }

     //prinf suffixes
    for (k = 0; k<c2; k++)
    {
        printf("\tsuffixes[%d] = %s",k,suffixes[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //compare the prefixes and suffixes

    c = 0 ;
    for (j = 0; j < c1; j++)
    {
        for(k=0 ; k < c2 ; k++)
        {
            printf("\nprefixes[%d] = %s , suffixes[%d] = %s\n ",j,prefixes[j],k,suffixes[k]);

            if (strcmp(prefixes[j], suffixes[k])==0)
            {
                c = c + 1 ;
            }
        }
    }

  }
  }
```

OUTPUT (Some part of OUTPUT) :-

```
prefixes[0] = ab    prefixes[1] = ab   //it should be prefixes[0] = a   prefixes[1] = ab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't allocating any strings. The only strings that you have in `lps` are `tmp1` and `tmp2`. You then make assignments like this:

```
prefixes[c1] = tmp1;
```

That assigns a pointer but does not copy the contents of the string. You'll end up with every entry in `prefixes` pointing to the same string, `tmp1`. And likewise for `suffixes`.

You'll need to use `malloc` and `strcpy` to make new string instances.

In the code you have commented out calls to `strcpy`. I suspect you tried these and encountered runtime errors. Those runtime errors were because you did not allocate any memory. The corrected code would look like:

```
prefixes[c1] = malloc(strlen(tmp1)+1);
strcpy(prefixes[c1], tmp1);
```

And similarly for `suffixes`.

In production quality code you'd include error checking. And you'd want to make sure that you call `free()` on any pointer returned by the calls `malloc()`, once you had finished with it.

I'd also question the use of C variable length arrays, VLAs. In your code, `prefixes`, `suffixes`, `tmp1` and `tmp2` are all VLAs. Using VLAs can readily lead to stack overflow if you have large array dimensions. My instincts say that heap allocation is what you need here.

Comment: I tried strcpy , but it dint give any run time error , but also it dint solve my problem .

Comment: Calling `strcpy` won't help unless you actually allocate some memory.

Comment: Sir , Even if the memory was not allocated , then also how did the tmp1 variables were being assigned to prefixes element , Why this did not show any error ??

Comment: `prefixes[c1] = tmp1` is a pointer assignment. Every element in `prefixes[]` would have ended up pointing to the same string, `tmp1`. And so it would have appeared that all the strings had the same value. In fact there was just one string, and lots of pointers pointing to it.

Comment: Sir , i think this can solved by emptying the tmp1 string everytime its use is finished ,but how to empty or nullify a string ?

Comment: To make an empty string you write `*tmp = '\0';` That would not solve the problem that I described. You'd then end up with all the elements pointing at an empty string. I think perhaps you are not connecting 100% with how pointers to char arrays (aka strings) work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27231/discussion-between-codejack-and-david-heffernan)